# How to show/hide a div on clicking toggle switch jquery and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello im facing an issue opening a div and closing a div on click on toggle switch .

```js
$('.tog').on('click', function() {
  $('.cntr').show();
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ca2222;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}


/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/

.on {
  display: none;
}

.on,
.off {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked+.slider .on {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+.slider .off {
  display: none;
}


/*--------- END --------*/


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tog">
  <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
        <div class="slider round">
            <!--ADDED HTML --><span class="on">ON</span><span class="off">OFF</span><!--END-->
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="cntr">Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Praesent sapien massa, convallis
  a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque
  nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem.</div>
```

Comment: I haven't deleted code pen link please check

Comment: added a snippet

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki We should *not* copy the code from other sites, unless the OP gives *explicit* permission to copy it to SO *and* we know the OP is, *in fact*, the copyright holder, or the license for the code in the other location is compatible with CC BY-SA 3.0 (e.g. pastebin.com, which also uses CC BY-SA 3.0). By posting on SE, it becomes licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0, which may conflict with other licensing. Copying the code has significant copyright issues, and should be done only by someone specifically authorized to release it under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license (i.e. the copyright holder).

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Please see [Pasting Fiddle snippet into original question as an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344484/3773011) and [Edits that add OP's code from 3rd party site where the license is unavailable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698/3773011). For specifically codepen.io: All [public pens are licensed](https://blog.codepen.io/legal/terms-of-service/) under the [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), which means that you can copy it, but **must** include the copyright notice and the MIT License text along with the copy.

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @Makyen , The code belongs to the author of the OP, we're just trying to help him to add a snippet to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working Pen](https://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/KybNdO?editors=0000)**.

That happen because of the way you're attaching the click event, you should attach it to the lower level `span` :

```
$('.slider span').on('click', function() {
  $('.cntr').toggle(); 
});
```

Snippet:

```js
$('.slider span').on('click', function() {
  $('.cntr').toggle();
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ca2222;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}


/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/

.on {
  display: none;
}

.on,
.off {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked+.slider .on {
  display: block;
}

input:checked+.slider .off {
  display: none;
}


/*--------- END --------*/


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tog">
  <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
        <div class="slider round">
            <!--ADDED HTML --><span class="on">ON</span><span class="off">OFF</span><!--END-->
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="cntr">Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Praesent sapien massa, convallis
  a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque
  nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem.</div>
```

Comment: I think you are using checkbox i need that code working with toggle switch.

Comment: Its working fine on first time when you toggle on second click its not working @zakaria.

Comment: The problem remains @prad  ?

Comment: yes if you toggle again and again you will know @zak